# Windows bat - calling programs for different cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, call

I wonder if I can execute some programs for different cmd's using .bat file. Look at this example .bat file:

```
start cmd //number one
start cmd //number two

ping localhost //call in number one
ping 192.168.1.100 //call in number two
```

I know that both will be executed in main window (the window where I started .bat file), but I think its easy to get the idea. This code is quite useless, but its just an example.

Thanx for all replies.

EDIT: I know about /k switch, but any way to do this not using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your commands with

```
start cmd /k ping localhost
start cmd /k ping 192.168.1.100
```

That will start two new command line prompts, run the ping command in each one seperately and both windows and the [/k](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true) switch will make them stay open afterwards.

Ah, posted before your edit ... ;) The only way to interact with a shell is giving it a command to be executed when it starts. There is no way to have interaction between shells

Comment: any way to do this without /k? Or maybe its good to call /k "sth.bat"?

Comment: edited my answer ... There's no chance to tell a shell to execute a given command other than the starting command. Of course, you can execute another batch file ;)

Answer (score 1):

CMD.EXE has two parameters, /C and /K, which let you specify a command to execute. /C closes the window when the command is finished, whereas /K keeps it running.

If you want to excute multiple commands within a single window, you'll need to concatenate them with && or similar - this will require quoting; `CMD /?` will tell you all the details on that - or you can have it start a batch file containing the commands.